# A version of box.com for local lan?

Tags: windows, dropbox, lan, sharepoint

Boss constraint: not allowed to store anything in the cloud.

Requirements:

- Version tracking
- Tags

I like the UI of box.com or dropbox.com or google drive, but not sharepoint. Its smarter cleaner easier and would induce our team to use it more than sharepoint, which imo is off-putting and clunky and we use 10 year old version anyway and boss is not gonna upgrade.

Is there something as easy as box.com (drag and drop, modern ui) for local windows lan use?

Comment: Why not just use windows shared folders? (assuming all your machines are connected to each other)

Comment: @aman207, I edited my question with some requirements, sorry.

Comment: You want lazy man's version tracking, huh? Where the Box does it for you. Of course, if your users you use a real version control system, then you could use shared folders. Worth thinking about, if you don't get an answer. Can you tell us roughly what sort of thing you would be sharing & why your want versioning?

Comment: Alternatively, you could use shared folders, if you could find a back up program that monitors a directory for changed and makes backups with a version number or date/timestamp.

Comment: @Mawg, it's mostly documentation. I know I want tags b/c that makes things appear in multiple places but there's only one copy. The versioning is someone else's sticking point; I guess they want it so they can make sure other versions are older / newer, etc. Not sure in your comment the connection between "real version control" and shared folders. Those seem like mutually exclusive options.

Comment: " I want tags b/c that makes things appear in multiple places but there's only one copy""- keep one copy & add some links? If you do't, those multiple copies **will** get out of synch. For versions, I strongly recommend version control - also for dox, not just code (for code, it is totally unacceptable not to, even for  single developer). Backups with version numbers was meant as an alternative to version control.(as a last resort, but I won't recommend it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out File Apartment, http://www.fileapartment.com , they provide on-site licensing/install thats the same as their cloud.

Comment: Thanks, I'm checking the price of local server / local client.

Comment: They would not tell me the price via website or email, which means $$$ - it's probably over the tiny budget my boss would allow for something so low priority in our organization, such as documenatation, esp. when we already have SharePoint.